# Is it possible to apply a custom alert template to only one particular SharePoint 2007 site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-alerts

Reading the answers to previous questions regarding SharePoint alerts, I have found many interesting information on how to define a custom template, for example: [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx)

But it looks like such customizations will actually erase the default template and impact the whole farm. Is there any way to deploy a custom alert template to only one site collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs for [STSADM -o UpdateAlertTemplate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd278299(office.12).aspx) you can use the -url param to target a particular site collection

```
stsadm -o updatealerttemplates

  -url <Specifies the URL name to a site collection.>

  [-filename <file name>]

  [-lcid <language>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert Template is just a Workflow. Create your custom workflow in SP Designer or through Code and install the workflow only in that Site template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it looks like we're not on the same page. I want to customize the email that is sent to users when they create an alert on a list (through the action menu -> "alert me").